# Position DIV with position absolute above DIV with position fixed

Tags: html, css

Here's my problem:
http://www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/company/

My client asked me to align the image slider to the top of the page. I made a black bar with position fixed, (you can see this bar at the very top of the page) and it is at the right place.

Now, What I need to do is align the imageslider right below it...

I can later set the bar with height: 0px and make it disappear, and just show the imageslider.

The imageslider cannot be position: fixed... it needs to scroll along with the page.

Thanks for any help!

```css
.upperfixedbanner {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;
}

.upperfixedbanner > .sliderhomepage {
display:block;
  position: absolute;
width:100%;
top: 0px;
margin-top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upperfixedbanner">
</div>

<div class="sliderhomepage">
<!--SHORTCODE OF SLIDER-->
  </div>
```

MORE INFO: C

CMS: Wordpress
Plugins: Meta Slider (for image slider)
WP-Bakery Visual Composer (my client told me she would have to update the site very often.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question. Do you want the slider to appear above your hear and under the balck bar?

Comment: Hi!
No... what I want is to show the slider below of the top of the browser... behind the main menu... the black bar will disappear... 

I thought of using it to stick the slider to it... 

Sorry for my english... I'm not quite used to write in it anymore.

Comment: I want the page to look like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1qAQm1oyIJVcWtuampTVkx1cGM

Comment: `sliderhomepage` should be under `upperfixedbanner`?

Comment: Yes.... to tell you the truth... the upperfixedbanner it's not necessary... All i want to do is align the sliderhomepage to the top of the page... 
it cannor be position: fixed, cuz it needs to be scrollable...

Comment: I just made the upperfixedbanner to try to align the sliderhomepage to it... it didn't work... but the upperfixedbanner is not necessary if i can align the slider to the top of the page.

Comment: and 'position :absolute; top:0` doesn't do that?

Comment: No... It's already setted like that.

Comment: I'm just tired.... i'll make the slider disappear in small screen resolutions.... I think is the best solution... The images of the slider would be unreadable anyway...

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the position and then introduce a top margin, I suggest trying:

```html
.upperfixedbanner > .sliderhomepage {
display:block;
position: static;
width:100%;
top: 0px;
margin-top:10px;
left:0px;
}
```